# Github Organization Memeber's permissions to run actions only

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to give an organization member in Github permission to run actions (or even a specific action) ONLY? No forking, no pushing, no pr.
(I know it is possible using REST endpoint by configuring Github Token permissions)

P.S.I am not sure actually if this question is needed to be posted here or in ServerFault but i hope i'm in a right place.